# Ionic 3 + Firebase Storage Get Profile Image

Tags: javascript, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

**I have this code:**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////CROP + UPLOAD FOR FIREBASE STORAGE//////////////////////////

  // Return a promise to catch errors while loading image
  getMedia(): Promise<any> {
    // Get Image from ionic-native's built in camera plugin
    return Camera.getPicture(this.options)
      .then((fileUri) => {
        // Crop Image, on android this returns something like, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/...'
        // Only giving an android example as ionic-native camera has built in cropping ability
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          return fileUri
        } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
          // Modify fileUri format, may not always be necessary
          fileUri = 'file://' + fileUri;
          /* Using cordova-plugin-crop starts here */
        return Crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 100 });
      }
      }).then((path) => {
         // path looks like 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.foo.bar/cache/1477008080626-cropped.jpg?1477008106566'
        //  console.log('Cropped Image Path!: ' + path);
        path; // return the path of file
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, FE=>{
          FE.file(file=>{
             const FR=new FileReader()
             FR.onloadend = ((res: any)=>{
               let AF=res.target.result
               let blob=new Blob([new Uint8Array(AF)], {type: 'image/jpg'});       
               this.upload(blob)
             });
             FR.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
             })
           })
         })
       }

       upload(blob:Blob){
         const currentUserId = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid; // get user UID in firebase
         this.Fbref.child(`Profile/${currentUserId}/img`).put(blob); //path in firebase storage


         ////GET Image URL 
         this.Fbref.child(`Profile/${currentUserId}/img` ).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
         console.log("the URL Image is: " + url);
         url;
         let photoURL = this.url

});}
```

It is working perfectly, does the image cut and then upload .... but I am not able to save the URL of the image inside the user profile DOC in the Firestore database.

Need to put as photoURL: (URL Image)

**Does anyone know how to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**
**Adding the code below worked perfectly**

```
savephotoURL(){
  const currentUserId = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
  this.Fbref.child(`Profile/${currentUserId}/img` ).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
  console.log("the URL Image is: " + url);
  let imageURL = url
  return imageURL
}).then((imageURL) => {
  this.database.doc(`ProfileUser/${currentUserId}/`).update({photoURL:imageURL})  })// save url in Firestore database realtime
}
```

Comment: Hello @Juliano JC do you have a repo on this? uploading and displaying image ionic 3 with firebase am experiencing some problems. I will appreciate your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! ... I created a repository now, it is in the link below, I hope it can help you ... I also took time to get the code to work .. if there is any doubt send it in github [https://github.com/Julianojc/Firebase-Storage-Upload]

Comment: Lemme me have a look ,much appreciated.