# Ionic 3 - image loader not working for firebase storage images

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I am using the Ionic image Loader plugin to cache and load images within my app

https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader

```
<img-loader [src]="user?.picture" useImg></img-loader>
```

This works fine when the image is not from my firebase storage, however when it is the download URL provided by firebase storage - it fails to loads and gives me a useless error on the xcode console.

```
ERROR: ERROR [object Object]
```

This problem is limited to the app running on the physical IOS device, but on chrome, it is absolutely fine.

MODULE.TS FILE

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EditSkillPage } from './edit-skill';
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EditSkillPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(EditSkillPage),
    IonicImageLoader,
  ],
})
export class EditSkillPageModule {}
```

Comment: Can you add more code? your line here doesn't look right: <img-loader [src]="user?.picture useImg></img-loader>

Comment: Sergey is right, we probably need more code to diagnose what is going on. I doubt you missed something this simple, but in your `<img-loader [src]="user?.picture useImg></img-loader>` that you put in the question, you are missing the ending `"`

Comment: @SergeyRudenko the npm package, once installed, handles everything - all that is required to have it working is the 'img-loader' tag and the ImageLoader in the module.ts file - as i stated, it all works fine for any image, apart from the images from firebase storage

Comment: Debug your src, isn't the full path of the image...Go deeper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 3 + Firebase Storage Get Profile Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864505/ionic-3-firebase-storage-get-profile-image)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (With firebase storage):

```
<img-loader src={{data.dataImgURL}} useImg></img-loader>
```

The [doc](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader) is pretty clear.